# ColorAnimation doesn't work if TargetProperty is set using Converter?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a DateTemplate for my NoOneCares model, which is a simple Path.

Now, I want my Path to blink 3 times (Storyboard, ColorAnimation on Path.Fill), when the DataTrigger is triggered.

The example below crashes every time I trigger the DataTrigger:

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object instance.

But when I set the Fill property directly Fill="Red" (and not with a ValueConverter), it works perfectly.

Why is this the case? I still need that Converter to set Fill to the correct color :/

```
 <DataTemplate DataType ="{x:Type models:NoOneCares}">
            <Path Stroke="White" Data="M 5,15 L5,10 L10,0 L 0,0 L 5,10" >

            <Path.Fill>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource colorConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="NoOneCares"></Binding>
                    <Binding Path="NoOneCares"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Path.Fill>

                <Path.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Path">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimationTrigger}" Value="{StaticResource numberTest}">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Name="fsadf">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3x" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3"
                                             Value="White"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Path.Style>
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the converter returns a freezed (immutable) brush, e.g. `Brushes.Red`. You can check this by `IsFrozen` property. Such objects cannot be changed.

You should clone the brush by calling `Clone()` method and return the cloned object - it's not frozen and can be changed.